# multiple subplots including one plot is 2grid plot

Tags: matplotlib

I am trying to create multiple subplots using matplotlib. There are total 8 figures need to be plotted (4rows*2columns). The first figure is a 2grid plot. The second figure is a simple bar plot.  Now I plot them correctly individually. However, if I integrate them using the multiple subplots, it keeps on returning stacked wired plots.
 [image]

The first figure i.e.a 2grid chart I am using`plt.subplot2grid`

```
fig=plt.figure()
ax1=plt.subplot2grid((4,1),(0,0),rowspan=2,colspan=1)
plt.title('This is the first chart-top grid')
ax1.set_ylabel("Volume",color='b')
ax2=plt.subplot2grid((4,1),(2,0),rowspan=2,colspan=1,sharex=ax1)

ax1.plot(df["Date"],linewidth=0.5,color='b')
ax1.plot(df["Volume"],linewidth=0.5,color='g')

ax2.plot(df["Value"],linewidth=1,color='r')
ax2.set_ylabel("dollar",color='b')
ax2.axhline(y=0,color='k',linewidth=1)
ax2.spines['top'].set_visible(False)
ax2.yaxis.set_ticks_position('right')
fig.subplots_adjust(hspace=0)
plt.title('This is the first chart-bottom grid')
```

The second figure is a simple bar chart

```
fig=plt.figure()
ax=cuimport.plot('Date','Volume1',kind='bar',
legend=False,facecolor='g',grid=True)
plt.ylabel('tonnes')
plt.title('This is the second chart-bar')
plt.show()
```

I have tried add something like `plt.subplot(4,2,1)` and `plt.subplot(4,2,2)`(allowing another 6 figures later)at the beginning of each plot in order to locate them but failed. The second bar plot been squeezed into the top gird of the (i.e., the 2grid) plot. very nasty. 
What's the solution to this?

Comment: Your grid is only 1 column. It needs to be `plt.subplot2grid((4,2))`

Comment: I thought that (4,1) or (4,2) as you suggested only has matter to to with the first figure plot.